# setting up iPhone P2P only over bluetooth and without GKPeerPickerController

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, p2p, bonjour, gamekit

I want to use a custom interface to connect with other iDevices in a p2p game. I know I can either use `GKSession` and `GKSessionDelegate` or use the lower level Bonjour browsing. But both of them will search for devices both over bluetooth AND wifi.

I want to list only bluetooth devices. I know this was answered in the past as impossible, but the Flight Control app seems to be able to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I thought I would answer to let you know that YOU ARE NOT ALONE, I am trying to do the same thing and it is kicking my butt! This link might help you:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40710-gamekit-api.html
I am trying to setup a server/client relationship and that requires me to use my own custom interface too.

Comment: The 8th post on that link shows exactly how to do it. Saved for my next project, thanks!

Comment: I'll have to try it. Will that method hide wifi clients and show only bluetooth ones?